# What is the difference between "wird" und "ist"?

Tags: verb, standard-german

What is the difference between "wird" and "ist"?
I have read some articles and according to it, I use "ist" in the below sentence:

"The keyboard is used for typing"

> Die Tastatur ist zum Tippen verwendet.

But the translation shows:

> Die Tastatur wird zum Tippen verwendet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yust as Kilian Foth explained, it has to do with an action that is beeing performed or has been performed and therefore is finished.

> Der Koffer wird gepackt. (The suitcase is beeing packed)

means that its's an ongoing action and it hasn't been finished yet, while

> Der Koffer ist gepackt. (The suitcase is packed)

is an finished action.
But we are still in the `Present-Tense`, not the past.

> Der Koffer wird gepackt werden (The suitcase will be packed) (Future)

> Der Koffer wird gepackt. (The suitcase is beeing packed) (Present, task ongoing)

> Der Koffer ist gepackt. (the suitcase is packed) (Present, task finished)

> Der Koffer wurde gepackt. (The suitcase was packed) (Past)

> Der Koffer ist gepackt worden. (The suitcase has been packed) (Past Perfect)

Long things short: If you want to translate `is + Verb (eg. "is used")`, it would be correct like this: `wird + Verb (eg. "wird benutzt")`. Also, the first example-sentence is wrong, because it has an additional verb at its end.

> Die Tastatur ist zum Tippen.

Is perfectly fine, but its an different sence and question. `"What is it the keyboard for? The keyboard is for typing."` --> `"Wofür ist die Tastatur? Die Tastatur ist zum Tippen."`

Hope that helps a little ;)

Comment: *Almost* correct; but unfortunately "the suitcase is packed" etc. translates very well into "der Koffer *ist* gepackt", so that your general rule "is + verb [in fact, past participle] => *wird*" is plain wrong. In order to emphasize a current process in English one uses the present continuous, in this case passive: "The suitcase is *being* packed" => "der Koffer *wird* [gerade] gepackt", as opposed to "the suitcase is [already completely] packed" => "der Koffer ist [bereits vollständig] gepackt".

Answer (score 6):

Your first German example is quite wrong. The simple passive is constructed with 'werden', never with 'sein':

> Die Tastatur wird zum Tippen verwendet.

The *Zustandspassiv* (combination of past participle + *sein*) is only used to express the result of an action with *perfective aspect*:

> Der Koffer ist gepackt.

Using a keyboard is a continuous (or at the most, iterative) action, so it takes the normal passive.

Comment: IMHO the aspect of the *Zustandspassiv* is rather resultative than perfective.